# What is the syntactic function of "a lot more" in this sentence?

Tags: syntax

> I think we’re going to see **a lot** more of her.

As far as I know, "**a lot**" is a quantifier, as is "**more**".

I would like to know which function one or the other represents - In addition to knowing if the example follows the **grammar**.

The question arose because I don't remember seeing **two quantifiers together**.

**Thanks** :))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*A lot* isn't a quantifier (you can't say "A lot bread").

*A lot **of*** is a quantifier.

I don't know how the current analyses deal with *a lot*. It seems to be an adverbial, but in most contexts it can only follow, not precede (*He talks a lot*, but not **He a lot talks*).

But with comparatives it can only precede (*I got there a lot quicker*, but not **I got there quicker a lot* - that would be interpreted as *a lot* = *many times*). But that's where *a lot more*, *a lot less* belong.

Comment: That's the answer I was looking for! Thank you, Mr. Fine.